# Overwrite existing file

Tags: java, copy, hsqldb, overwrite

I want to overwrite 2 files.
Both files store information about my in memory database (HSQLDB):
db.data and db.script

My following code should do this:

```
public class DBReset {
    public Path db_data = Paths.get("db_sep/db_backup/db.data");
    public Path db_script = Paths.get("db_sep/db_backup/db.script");
    public Path dest_data = Paths.get("db_sep/db.data");
    public Path dest_script = Paths.get("db_sep/db.script");

    public void discard() throws IOException {
        Files.copy(this.db_data, this.dest_data, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.copy(this.db_script, this.dest_script, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

However if I use

```
public Class anotherClass {
    new DBReset.discard();
    // do something with DB
    new DBReset.discard();
    // do something other with DB
}
```

The second `discard()` does not overwrites my files.

I use `discard()` to reset my database to its original state. Please don't ask / tell me there are other ways to reset the database, the actual problem is why it does not overwrite my files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not SHUTDOWN the database. If the database is open, the `.data` file cannot be overwritten. Execute the SQL statement below when you finish work with the database:

```
 SHUTDOWN
```

This should be executed by the program that accesses the database :

```
new DBReset.discard();
// do something with DB -- then perform SHUTDOWN in the same java process
```

Comment: If I do that, all following connections to the DB can't be established.  What I want to do:  `new DBReset.discard(); // make sure DB instance is the original one` and then tests for User 1 restricted Database Access after that `new DBReset.discard(); // reset DB` and then test for another user

Comment: It is simple. You must shutdown after you access the db and before you delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `SHUTDOWN` does not work.

```
public void discard() throws IOException, SQLException {
    Connection c = DBConnectFactory.getDataSource.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = c.preparedStatement("SHUTDOWN"); 
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();
    c.close();

    Files.copy(this.db_data, this.dest_data, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.copy(this.db_script, this.dest_script, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Throws at first line of `Connection c = DBConnectFactory.getDataSource.getConnection();` `java.sql.Exception: error in script file line: 1 unknown token: ...` lots of Unknown Sources.

Also tested in my `runQuery(String query)` - that opens a connection and then executes the given query via PreparedStatement - to force the `SHUTDOWN`, but it throws the same error as above, where I should get a Connection at `getConnection()`.

What I want to do is:

1. Restore Original DB Instance.
2. Do some stuff with the DB, `SELECT`, `INSERT` and then do some assertions. Basically test some stuff against the Database.
3. Restore Original DB Instance.
4. Do some other tests against the Database.

PS: I'm using HSQLDB in file mode.